# .htaccess rule from read.cfm?id=PARAM to /?p=PARAM

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a general permament redirection rule for every

```
mysite.com/read.cfm?id=NUMBER
```

to

```
mysite.com/?p=NUMBER
```

I'm trying something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\read.cfm$ /?p=$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect **/read.cfm?id=12345** to **/?p=12345** you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^read.cfm$ /?p=%1 [L,NC,R]
```